# How to remove the displayed controls in the panel after each selection from the DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am struggling right now with the following issue; I have a panel control that has more than one GridView. Only one GridView will be displayed based on the selection from the DropDownList.

Let us assume that we have three GridViews and we have a DropDownList with three options; A, B and C. If I select A, the first GridView will be displayed. After that, if I select B, the second GridView will be displayed in addition to the first displayed GridView. What I want is after selecting any option from the dropdownlist, the GridView and Label control should be removed and replaced with the new result.

**So how can I do that?**

***My ASP.NET code:***

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem>Please Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:GridView>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
```

***C# Code:***

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != null)
        {
            int option = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;

            var myList2 = new List<string>();
            myList2.Add("Test");
            myList2.Add("Test");

            var myList3 = new List<string>();

            switch (option)
            {
                case 1:
                    if (myList2.Count > 0)
                    {
                        GridView1.DataSource = myList2;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                        GridView1.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessage.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        lblMessage.Text = "No Data!";
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (myList3.Count > 0)
                    {
                        GridView1.Visible = false;
                        GridView2.DataSource = myList3;
                        GridView2.DataBind();
                        GridView2.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessage.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        lblMessage.Text = "No Data!";
                    }
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    if (myList2.Count > 0)
                    {
                        GridView1.Visible = false;
                        GridView2.Visible = false;
                        GridView3.DataSource = myList2;
                        GridView3.DataBind();
                        GridView3.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessage.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        lblMessage.Text = "No Data!";
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

NOTE: As you see in my C# above that in each case in the switch statement, I am removing the controls of the preceding case but this is not the right way, because I need to remove whether GridView or Label controls after selecting any item from the dropdownlist. So is there any way of taking care of this.

Comment: If i understood correctly. Wouldn't it be easier to rebind the same grid-view with the new data

Comment: Sounds like you want a [`MultiView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), with each `Grid` in its own [`View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.view%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Wahtever, yes, you are right. Would you kindly provide me with code excerpt as I am new to ASP.NET?

Comment: @RichardDeeming, I am looking at MultiView right now but I am concerned about the Label control as it shows a message as well. Would you kindly illustrate your idea to me by example?

Comment: @RichardDeeming, I think the label just show, there is not any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MultiView control as described here:

Change page like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>Please Select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:MultiView ID="MainMultiview" runat="server">
        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
            GridView 1
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:GridView>
            <br />
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
            GridView 2
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:GridView>
            <br />
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">
            GridView 3
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:GridView>
            <br />
        </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
```

and change code behind in C# class to like this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != null)
        {
            int option = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;

            var myList2 = new List<string>();
            myList2.Add("Test");
            myList2.Add("Test");

            var myList3 = new List<string>();

            switch (option)
            {
                case 1:
                    if (myList2.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //GridView1.DataSource = myList2;
                        //GridView1.DataBind();
                        //GridView1.Visible = true;
                        MainMultiview.SetActiveView(View1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessage.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        lblMessage.Text = "No Data!";
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (myList2.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //GridView1.Visible = false;
                        //GridView2.DataSource = myList3;
                        //GridView2.DataBind();
                        //GridView2.Visible = true;
                        MainMultiview.SetActiveView(View2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessage.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        lblMessage.Text = "No Data!";
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (myList2.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //GridView1.Visible = false;
                        //GridView2.Visible = false;
                        //GridView3.DataSource = myList2;
                        //GridView3.DataBind();
                        //GridView3.Visible = true;
                        MainMultiview.SetActiveView(View3);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessage.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        lblMessage.Text = "No Data!";
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice gridview can not bind to list of string. But multiview works greate.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not binding GridView to the List. This is just as an example. In reality, the GridView is bound to the Database. So how will your solution will fit my need since I need to use the GridView to be bound to the database?

Comment: And What about the Label? If the table was displayed instead of the GridView in case that the GridView has no data, how the Label will be removed after selecting another option from the DropDownList?

Comment: How you want to bound gridviews to database? What is your datasource?

Comment: I Highly recommend that do not use label for `no data`. Just use EmptyDataTemplate as descirbed here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. As you recommended me, I used the EmptyDateTemplate. It is much better than Label control. Again, THANKS a lot for your help.